# How to pass an object from symfony controller to angularjs in order to define a variable with it?

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony, twig

I need to pre fill a TextType with some data initially but Angularjs keeps resetting my TextType to empty, even when I set value attribute to it... So, how can I initially define it with that value on page load? I need this keyword model to be set with the user email, adding value as an attribute doesn't work...

```
{{ form_row(form.keyword,  {'attr': {'ng-model': 'keyword'}} )}}
```

My user is sent in the controller as an argument.

```
public function addAction(User $user = null, Request $request)
```

And this is my Angularjs controller, what I wish to achieve is initially declare keyword with the user email.

```
//$scope.keyword = $user.email.
```

What I am doing right now is initially setting it to empty, and that's why it keeps presetting the value attribute to empty.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you have to use the Symfony Serializer component to serialize your user then pass this serialized object as attribute to your twig and deserialize it in javascript:

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class DefaultController extends AbstractController {
    ...
    public function addAction(User $user = null, Request $request, SerializerInterface $serializer){
        ...
        $serializedUser = $serializer->serialize($user, 'json');
        return $this->render('default/add_action.html.twig', [
            'user' => $serializedUser,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

Beware that if you have entity associations in your user entity you may face circular reference problems.

In this case you have to use serialization groups (doc [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#attributes-groups)) when serializing your user like this:

```
$serializedUser = $serializer->serialize($user, 'json', ['groups' => ['add-action']]);
```

Finally in your twig, you'll have to do something like that in your container div:

```
<div id="form-container" ng-init="user = {{ user|e('html_attr') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.keyword = "{{ user.email }}";
```

Since twig and Angularjs uses the same interpolation "{{}}". You can configure angularjs to use other interpolation string such as "[[ ]]";